# How do you write an IF formula to review 4 separate cells and apply separate WORKDAY formulas?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I need to create one formula which reviews 4 separate cells and determines which WORKDAY formula to apply. How do I nest the multiple IF statements correctly (or use IF(AND) if that is more appropriate?)?

Start:
=IF($C17="ON HOLD","ON HOLD", [all of the remaining formulas should nest here]

If L17 is blank, if Q17 is blank, if $M$13 is “Batch” = WORKDAY(H17,$B$137,$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is blank, if Q17 is blank, if $M$13 is Not “Batch” = WORKDAY(H17,M17,$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is blank, if Q17 is Not blank, if $M$13 is “Batch” = WORKDAY(H17,SUM($B$137+Q17),$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is blank, if Q17 is Not blank, if $M$13 is Not “Batch” = WORKDAY(H17,SUM(M17+Q17),$A$95:$B$108)

If L17 is Not blank, if Q17 is blank, if $M$13 is “Batch” = WORKDAY(L17,$B$137,$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is Not blank, if Q17 is blank, if $M$13 is Not “Batch” = WORKDAY(L17,M17,$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is Not blank, if Q17 is Not blank, if $M$13 is “Batch” = WORKDAY(L17,SUM($B$137+Q17),$A$95:$B$108)
If L17 is Not blank, if Q17 is Not blank, if $M$13 is Not “Batch” = WORKDAY(L17,SUM(M17+Q17),$A$95:$B$108)

Comment: What version of Excel?  The latest 365 and 2019 version (maybe earlier) have a `SWITCH()` function that would really simplify the logic.  Otherwise, you're going to be stuck with a complex set of several nested `IF()` statements.

Comment: 2019 version. SWITCH( ) appears to be a formula option (though I've never used it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old-school way of doing it, if you don't have a `SWITCH()` function:

```
=IF($C17="ON HOLD","ON HOLD",
   IF(L17="",
     IF(Q17="",
       IF($M$13="Batch",WORKDAY(H17,$B$137,$A$95:$B$108),WORKDAY(H17,M17,$A$95:$B$108)),
       IF($M$13="Batch",WORKDAY(H17,SUM($B$137+Q17),$A$95:$B$108),WORKDAY(H17,SUM(M17+Q17),$A$95:$B$108))
     ),
     IF(Q17="",
       IF($M$13="Batch",WORKDAY(L17,$B$137,$A$95:$B$108),WORKDAY(L17,M17,$A$95:$B$108)),
       IF($M$13="Batch",WORKDAY(L17,SUM($B$137+Q17),$A$95:$B$108),WORKDAY(L17,SUM(M17+Q17),$A$95:$B$108))
     )
   )
 )
```

I do not have the later version of Excel to see how `SWITCH()` works, so I cannot provide an example of that here.

You may have to change the `L17=""` and `Q17=""` to `ISBLANK(L17)` and `ISBLANK(Q17)`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to do without `IF`:

```
=WORKDAY(L17+ISBLANK(L17)*H17
 ;ISBLANK(Q17)*(($M$13="Batch")*$B$137+($M$13<>"Batch")*M17)
 +NOT(ISBLANK(Q17))*(($M$13="Batch")*SUM($B$137+Q17)+($M$13<>"Batch")*SUM(M17+Q17))
 ;$A$95:$B$108)
```